# Почему при создании запись в таблице автоматически ссылается на id записи другой таблицы?

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть две сущности:

```
public class TimeOfSessionEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "timeOfSessionId")
    private Long timeOfSessionId;

    @Column(name = "timeOfSession")
    private Timestamp timeOfSessionDate;

    private Long movieId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dateOfSessionId")
    private DateOfSessionEntity dateOfSession;
}
```

И

```
public class DateOfSessionEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "dateOfSessionId")
    private Long dateOfSessionId;

    @Column(name = "dateOfSessionTime")
    private Timestamp dateOfSession;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dateOfSession", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<TimeOfSessionEntity> timeOfSession = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Когда я сохраняю в бд сущность *TimeOfSessionEntity*,то автоматически запись ссылается на таблицу DateOfSessionEntity с id=0.
т.е. я хочу вначале создать запись в TimeOfSessionEntity, а потом уже выбрать на какой id ссылаться в DateOfSessionEntity. что я делаю не так?
при сохранении TimeOfSessionEntity внешний ключ не указываю.

Comment: Посмотрите как определена колонка в базе. Похоже она `not null default 0`

Comment: @talex посмотрел, дефолтное значение null стоит

Comment: Загадка. Попробуйте брейкпоинт в сеттер поставить. Надо понять кто значение туда засовывает. Хибернейт сам  такого делать не должен.

Comment: @talex Почему не должен, а кто будет это делать?

Answer (score 0):

Значение `id` обычно генерится в Hibernate. Надо бы поставить аннотацию `@GeneratedValue`.

Более подробно можно почитать про эту аннотацию [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html).

Значение внешнего ключа устанавливается если вы сохраняет оба объекта, или же поочередно, тогда зависимый объект берётся из сессии.